# What is the highest limit for boost-multiprecision cpp_int?

Tags: c++, biginteger, boost-multiprecision

I'm working on factoring large semi-prime numbers. I am working on Java but I am just curious to explore other options as well. I know C++ Boost multiprecision supports large numbers.

I found the following information from Boost page:

```
typedef number<cpp_int_backend<128, 128, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void> >   uint128_t;
typedef number<cpp_int_backend<256, 256, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void> >   uint256_t;
typedef number<cpp_int_backend<512, 512, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void> >   uint512_t;
typedef number<cpp_int_backend<1024, 1024, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void> > uint1024_t;
```

My question is, what is the limit of largest number of cpp_int type? In Java BigInteger supports upto 2^Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `cpp_int` does not have a [theoretical] maximum value

It's important to bear in mind that in Java, the maximum size of the value is constrained by the physical limitations of the Java Virtual Machine to represent a value. In the underlying implementation, Java (probably) implements `BigInteger` with something like this:

```
public class BigInteger {
    private long[] bits;//limited by the maximum size of an array in Java
    /*...*/
}
```

<sup><sup>Disclaimer: I do not know whether they use `long[]` or `int[]` to store bits.</sup></sup>

Similarly, in C++, `cpp_int` is, once you scrape away the abstractions, implemented with a pretty similar construction:

```
class boost::multiprecision::cpp_int {
    uint64_t * bits;
    uint64_t * end; //Points to the element-after-the-last in bits
    /*...*/
};
```

<sup><sup>Disclaimer Again: they probably do something a little smarter than this.</sup></sup>

What puts the theoretical limit on Java is the fact that the JVM places a hard cap on array sizes at `Integer.MAX_VALUE` because arrays are indexed with `int` instead of `long`. C++ can directly use pointers, so the maximum size of `cpp_int` in C++ is proportional to the maximum memory range that a pointer can address—which in 64-bit architectures is usually-but-not-always™ 2<sup>64</sup>-1; or in other words, the maximum value of `cpp_int` is 2<sup>2<sup>64</sup>-1</sup>-1, give-or-take an order of magnitude depending on how they implement the sign.

In environments that support larger pointers (or pointers that can address a larger range of memory), the maximum value is probably greater.

In practice, the largest value for `cpp_int` (and Java's `BigInteger`, for that matter) is the practical limit on how much memory your runtime environment is allowed to allocate.

Comment: In that case what are the differences between uint128_t, uint256_t, uint512_t and uint1024_t? @Xirema

Comment: @ManojBanik The names seem self-explanatory: they're each unsigned integers of size X bits, where X is `uintX_t`, so the maximum value of each number should be 2<sup>X</sup>-1